# Formating of Excel generated by VF page

Tags: visualforce, excel

I am generating an excel file from VF page. I would need some help in formating the excel sheet.
Can the width of the cells in the top row be different from the cells of the tables in the bottom. Something like we merge a few columns in Row A of excel sheet.

[image]

Here is my VF page

```
    <apex:page standardController="Quote" extensions="CVFE_GenerateExcelQuote" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#SalesForceExport.xls" cache="true" >
  <!--  contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#SalesForceExport.xls" cache="true" -->


    <head>
          <style>
              .aligncenter
              {
                  text-align:center;
              }
          </style>
      </head>

      <table>
          <tr>
              <td colspan="2"> 
                <table>
                  <tr>
                      <td style="width:500px; height: 95px;">
                           <img src="{!url}" /> <br/>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td>
                            Some Addrress
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                </table> 
              </td>
              <td width="100px">

              </td>
               <td width="100px">

              </td>
               <td width="100px">

              </td>
              <td>
                  <table>
                      <tr>


                          <td >John Doe</td>
                          <td >Billing</td>
                          <td >Traffic</td>
                          <td >Ad Ops</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>


                          <td >Vice President Sales</td>
                          <td >billing@a.com</td>
                          <td >Traffic@a.com</td>
                          <td >AdOps@a.com</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
             </td>
          </tr>

      </table>
        <apex:repeat value="{!OptionsSet}" var="f">
            <apex:outputText value="{!f}" /><br/>
                <apex:dataTable value="{!MapOptionQLI[f]}" var="s" style="border: 1px solid black;">
                    <apex:column value="{!s.Placement_Name__c}" />
                    <apex:column value="{!s.Start_Date__c}" style=" text-align:center;"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!s.End_Date__c}" style=" text-align:center;"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!s.Ad_Format__c}" style=" text-align:center;"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!s.Targetting__c}" style=" text-align:center;"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!s.Additional_Targetting__c}" style=" text-align:center;"/>                

                    <apex:column style=" text-align:center;">
                        <apex:facet name="header">Rate</apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputfield value="{!s.UnitPrice}"/>

                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column style=" text-align:center;">
                        <apex:facet name="header">Impressions</apex:facet>
                         <apex:outputfield value="{!s.Quantity}"/>

                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column style=" text-align:center;">
                        <apex:facet name="header">CPM/CPC</apex:facet>
                        <apex:outputfield value="{!s.Rate_Type__c}"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column value="{!s.Total_Investments__c}" style=" text-align:center;"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!s.Notes__c}" />
                </apex:dataTable>

        </apex:repeat>




    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Why not use an app from the appexchange for this?  Something like conga composer has already solved these issues.

Comment: yes, but they are not free. Its not something client is willing to pay as they dont have too much of creating documents

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it, but take a look at [this](http://appshark.com/blog/how-to-export-data-in-excel-using-visualforce/).

Instead of using HTML tags, it uses tags that are recognised by Excel.

In terms of XML markup, I think that page is slightly wrong, [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160226164343/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/brian_jones/archive/2005/06/27/433152.aspx) seems like a good example of how to style columns:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
    <ss:Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
        <ss:Table>
            <ss:Column ss:Width="80"/>
           <ss:Column ss:Width="80"/>
           <ss:Column ss:Width="80"/>
            <ss:Row>
                <ss:Cell>
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">First Name</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
                <ss:Cell>
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Last Name</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
                <ss:Cell>
                    <ss:Data ss:Type="String">Phone Number</ss:Data>
                </ss:Cell>
            </ss:Row>
        </ss:Table>
    </ss:Worksheet>
</ss:Workbook>
```